# Is it possible to have a shared context across unit tests in go test?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I am implementing a trie in Go as a way of learning the language. I want to write tests from the get go as a way of getting a feel for Go's approach to things.

One problem I am having when testing my trie is that I have to rebuild it for every unit test. Is there a way to reuse the same instantiation of my trie across unit tests? Ideally, I'd like a way to do this without any external dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: Just construct it in `func init()` in your `trie_test.go`. (Or even use a literal.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Volker. Can you elaborate a bit more? Would I call init at the beginning of every unit test? I guess I could memoize it.

Comment: @returneax init is called automatically by the go runtime when the program starts.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being a bit thick, but when init gets called, would I assign the stuff it initializes to a global scope?

Comment: @returneax, see [this](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution) for more info on `init()`

Comment: @returneax, yes global scope is the place to keep global stuff :-)

Comment: @volker I was hoping for a scope for groups of tests

Comment: Any way to also detect the teardown of the test suite?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind the extra dependency, the [gocheck](http://labix.org/gocheck) package provides the ability to group tests into suites.  You can then define `SetUpSuite` and `TearDownSuite` methods to perform initialisation and tear down of any resources shared by the tests in that suite.

Comment: IMHO the standard testing package should be a bit richer, along these lines. It feels too spartan.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear. Ideally, I'd like a way to do this without any external dependencies.

Comment: @returneax Without dependencies, it's up to you to write setup and teardown functions and call them. To make it really slick on yourself, you'd probably basically end up rewriting a Go testing library.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize it was so lightweight. Thanks Matt.

Comment: Well, `gocheck` is built on top of the standard `testing` library (you still run your tests with `go test`), so you could try and extract the suite functionality from it.  That said, `gocheck` makes a lot of tests more convenient to write and easier to understand, so I wouldn't dismiss it too quickly.